# Need to ignore duplicates entries in an autocomplete box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net

i have an input using the jquery autocomplete plugin.  with this i want to return 5 results.  I was making this happen by just entering 5 return results in the stored procedure that im using, but i want to remove duplicates, while still showing 5 results. im not sure the best way to go about doing this
here is my code behind for the callback page

```
Public Class SearchCallback
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Response.Clear()
    Dim searchText As String = Request("searchText")
    Dim searchField As String = Request("searchField")


    Dim dtCustomer As CustomerCollection = CustomerService.SearchRecords(searchText, searchField, "Contains", searchField, "Asc", CInt("1"), CInt("5"))
    Dim returnString As String
    If searchField = "Company" Then
        For Each drCustomer As Customer In dtCustomer
            If returnString = "" Then
                returnString = drCustomer.Company
            else
                returnString = returnString & "," & drCustomer.Company
            End If
        Next
        Response.Write(returnString)
```

i had a list of more searchfield options after that to give me the data i want.  Im putting the needed info into a string so i can use it with my javascript code as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".searchTextBox").autocomplete({
    source: callback,
    autoFill: true
});
});

var callback = function (request, response) {
var searchText = request.term;
var searchField = $(".ddlist > option:selected").attr("value");
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    url: "SearchCallback.aspx?searchText=" + searchText + "&searchField=" + searchField,
    success: function (data) {
        var splitData = data.split(",");
        response(splitData);
    }
});
}
```

everything works other then the duplication problem that im having.. please help!

---

its kinda messy but i got it working as i want with the following code

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Response.Clear()
    Dim searchText As String = Request("searchText")
    Dim searchField As String = Request("searchField")
    Dim lastValue As String
    Dim resultsCounter As Integer = 0

    Dim dtCustomer As CustomerCollection = CustomerService.SearchRecords(searchText, searchField, "Contains", searchField, "Asc", CInt("1"), CInt("100"))
    Dim returnString As String
    If searchField = "Company" Then
        resultsCounter = 0
        For Each drCustomer As Customer In dtCustomer
            If returnString = "" Then
                returnString = drCustomer.Company
                lastValue = drCustomer.Company
                resultsCounter += 1
            ElseIf resultsCounter < 6 Then
                If lastValue <> drCustomer.Company Then
                    returnString = returnString & "," & drCustomer.Company
                    lastValue = drCustomer.Company
                    resultsCounter += 1
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Response.Write(returnString)
```

Comment: this sounds more like a Data Access problem in SearchRecords method, you can use DISTINCT before LIMIT(5) to ensure what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of ORM framework are you using? With SQL the DISTINCT keyword is used for this, that might help

Comment: i would use that but for this im forced to use stored procedures and i do not have the option of giving that param

Comment: In stored procedures you are able to use the distinct keyword, because it is used within the query. Check http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: with my setup, this is the only place where i want distinct values, so i would have had to change all my code behind and webserveces andim lazy so i just did it manually in my codebehind. i added on my question with what i did.  upvote for the try! :D